# How to measure test coverage

Tags: windows, unit-testing, mootools, manual, test-coverage

How can i measure the coverage of the manual tests?
Are there tools to measure the coverage of the manual tests?
I have searched but all the articles refer to unit tests

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean? what tests do you refer to? MooTools UI tests? or?

Comment: I'm refering to manual tests on a big application. I'm trying to find a way or a tool to measure the coverage on my tests on new functionalities

Answer (score 0):

The tools for measuring coverage of manual tests are also manual. You need to count the possible execution branches of the code and those which you covered. Coverage would be this ration of covered/all